# Downloading Text from Articles

Tags: integrity

Is there any security measures that I should take when downloading article text from the web as far as file integrity? For example, I've written a bot that retrieves article text from a user's blog and saves them to disk. What measures would you recommend and/or enforce?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What kind of attacks are you concerned about? What is your objective (e.g. is it “download the article at this URL” or “download the article written by this author on this date”)?

Comment: I'll do my best. When downloading images, a safety measure to take is to md5Sum the images and verify that they haven't been changed or modified. In this case, I'm just downloading article text from various Wordpress blogs. I've already written the code to extract the data so that's taken care of. I wanted to know if there was anything I should be aware of when downloading text from pages.  @Gilles

Comment: Safety from what? If you take hashes of the images and store them next to the images, an attacker who can modify the images can also update the hashes to match.

Comment: That's very true, what would you recommend in preventing that then? @Gilles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm is this confidential information? if is already public domain.. why even worry about how secure it is? 
like if this was confidential and authorized level of access then I will do the copy over ssh.. scp just to mention a simple solution.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I figured as much, but I'm still learning security. I like to be safe.

Comment: is cool.. you can always check the live state of the article with wget/curl and compare with the downloaded version.. but honestly, if you are worried about people changing the information while you download... use scp.